# Access Django context data in get_initial

Tags: django

I have an expensive call in my view's get_context_data to calculate a field for the template. I would like to use this result in the view's get_initial_data to set the initial value of my_field but I cannot see how to access the context_data from within get_initial_data or how to pass it as a parameter.

```
def get_context_data( self, *args, **kwargs ):
    context = super().get_context_data( **kwargs )
    context['expensive_result'] = expensive_function()
    return context

def get_initial( self, *args, **kwargs ):
    initial = super().get_initial( **kwargs )
    # Initialise my_field with expensive result calculated in get_context_data
    initial['my_field'] = context['expensive_result']     # How to do this?
    return initial
```

Answer (score 1):

`get_initial` return `self.initial.copy()` by [docs](https://github.com/django/django/blob/551c997feaaa293987af8b05efc3634b93305fac/django/views/generic/edit.py#L10)

So, you can write:

```
def get_context_data( self, *args, **kwargs ):
    expensive_value = expensive_function()
    self.initial['my_field'] = expensive_value
    context = super().get_context_data( **kwargs )
    context['expensive_result'] = expensive_value
    return context
```

You need to call it before `get_context_data` 'super' calling, because it calls `get_initial` inside itself.

Or you can add field to your view class and write property for it:

```
class SomeView(CreateView):
    _expensive_value = None
    
    @propetry
    def expensive_value(self):
        if self._expensive_value is None:
            self._expensive_value = expensive_function()
        return self._expensive_value

    def get_context_data( self, *args, **kwargs ):
        context = super().get_context_data( **kwargs )
        context['expensive_result'] = self.expensive_value
        return context

    def get_initial( self, *args, **kwargs ):
        initial = super().get_initial( **kwargs )
        initial['my_field'] = self.expensive_value
        return initial
```

And using this propetry inside both `get_context_data` and `get_initial` will called `expensive_function` just one time.

Comment: But expensive function will called twice if it return `None`

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer LMA9. I went with your first suggestion. I'll upvote it once I have enough reputation :-)